# Is there a way to "paint bucket" in the Game Maker Room Editor?

Tags: game-maker

In the game I am working on, I have a lot of empty space I need to fill up with one type of object. Preferably, I just want to use a paint bucket type tool to fill the space easily. Is there a way I can do this, or am I stuck doing this by hand?

Answer (score 0):

No, only by hand. But if you really need it, you can use external editor like [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org) and then use data from it.
For example you can see [this](http://gmc.yoyogames.com/index.php?showtopic=583235) topic